# SQL Server bulk insert command fails importing textfile

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to dump the following txt into a table (using the wizard did not work either)

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin1CodesASCII.txt

using the following

```
drop table tempregions
create table TempRegions
( 
code varchar(500),
name varchar(500),
asciiName varchar(500),
somenumber varchar(500)
);

BULK INSERT GeoNames 
  FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\geonames\admin1CodesASCII.txt' 
        WITH( 

              FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
              ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'

            ) 
            go
```

getting the following error (using sql server 2012)

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (geonameid).

thanks for the help

Comment: And? Did you consider - ah - checking the data? Line 10 is not exactly THAT far into the dataset. Most people would check the data and post the findings here.

Comment: what exactly wrong with line 10?

Comment: `ā` may not exist in the code page you're using.

Comment: @Zoinky I do not know. YOU TELL ME. YOu have the data. You can look at line 10 of the data. I can not. See, you never post the line. Ups.

Comment: @TomTom either am drunk or you are.. the data is http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin1CodesASCII.txt as posted and nothing wrong with line 10

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson so how do i import this with these special characters?

Comment: @Zoinky You definitely are drunk. SImply said, I would say your problem is that this is not standard ASCII with the special characters. There goes the easy solution. You will have to define a codepage.

Comment: DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'

Answer (score 0):

The text contains non-standard ASCII characters and you fail to define a codepage. The error is there to protrect you. Find and define an appropriate codepage as per syntax at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx